# Concatenate AngularJS 2 drop down ng-options values to 1 drop down

Tags: angularjs, concatenation, ng-options, dropdown

Is it possible to concatenate 2 values in a model array ig-Model?

I need to capture two values and put them together into a new one so I can use that to display them in the drop down box with ng-options.

Something below into one drop down.

```html
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select> 
<select ng-model="depth" ng-options="p.range for d in depth "></select>
```

Result should Be:
Red Deep

Comment: **<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select>** 
**<select ng-model="depth" ng-options="p.range for d in depth "></select>**

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of colors ...

```
[{name:"red"}, {name:"green"}]
```

And an array of depths ...

```
[{range:'deep'}, {range:'very deep'}]
```

Can't you just create a new array of objects in your controller to end up with something like ...

```
[{name:"red", range:"deep"}, {name:"red", range:"very deep"},{name:"green", range:"deep"}, {name:"green", range:"very deep"}]
```

And then in your view do an ng-repeat on your new array?